# Token Replacement and Identification

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to acomplish the following and unsure of the best methods.

Take the following string as an example.

> %%%% START %%%%
>
> sit amet ipsum sagittis luctus eu id diam.  [%RC:3%]   Morbi suscipit
>   iaculis accumsan. Morbi laoreet consectetur nisl, luctus tempor felis
>   ultrices commodo. Praesent dui augue, interdum non rutrum vel,
>   vestibulum sit amet lorem. Nam sit amet erat elit, et porta mi.
>   Vestibulum non urna magna. Phasellus pharetra rutrum urna quis
>   tincidunt. Duis metus quam, fermentum sed ultricies id, tincidunt id
>   ipsum.    [%RC:1%]
>
> %%%% END %%%%

What i need to be able to do is take that string and firstly find all the occurences of the "tokens" `[%RC:(int)%]`, get the id that is contained within that token (which will be used to query data) and then replace that whole token with a new string.

How would i do this?  Any advice & guidance would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a dictionary that you can use to look up the replacement string, try using the overload of [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) that takes a `MatchEvaluator`:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
    text,
    @"\[%RC:(\d+)%\]",
    match => dict[int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value)]);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/aee7F)

Comment: will this simply replace teh contents in between the [%RC: %] or will it replace the whole string?  Would it be possible to get an array of all the tokens found so that i can loop through them??

Comment: Just saw it working online..i think you have actually created me a more elegant solution to my initial problem. I will try this now..thank you

Comment: Finding the overload containing the MatchEvaluator saved me a tonne of time (and LOC) -- thanks Mark!